# Return term_id's recursively

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
public function get_taxonomy_hierarchy( $taxonomy, $parent = 0 )
{
    $taxonomy = is_array( $taxonomy ) ? array_shift( $taxonomy ) : $taxonomy;
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, [ 'parent' => $parent ] );
    $children = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term->url = get_term_link( $term->term_id);
        $term->children = $this->get_taxonomy_hierarchy( $taxonomy, $term->term_id );
        $children[ ] = $term->id;
    }
    return $children;
}
```

My problem is that this function only returns direct descendants id's and ignores others. What am I missing here?

Comment: Fixed this with static array

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to push the `term_id`s to the children array, rather than just declaring `$children[ ] = $term->id;`

```
public function get_taxonomy_hierarchy( $taxonomy, $parent = 0 )
{
    $taxonomy = is_array( $taxonomy ) ? array_shift( $taxonomy ) : $taxonomy;
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, [ 'parent' => $parent ] );
    $children = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term->url = get_term_link( $term->term_id);
        $term->children = $this->get_taxonomy_hierarchy( $taxonomy, $term->term_id );

    array_push($children, $term->term_id);
    }
    return $children;
}
```

Also, shouldn't it be `$term->term_id;` in line 9 of your code?

Comment: It's the same array_push or $children[], still doesn't work. :D